# List not defined even when defined in earlier cases

Tags: python

```
prompt = "    Type add, show, edit, complete or exit:       "


while True:

    user_action = input( prompt.strip())
    match user_action:
            case "add":
                todo = input("Enter a todo:") + "\n"
                file= open("todos.txt", "r")
                todos = file.readlines()
                file.close()
                
                todos.append(todo)
                
                file= open("todos.txt", "w")
                file.writelines(todos)
                file.close()
            
            case "show" | "display":
                file=open('todos.txt', "r")
                todos= file.readlines()
                file.close()
                    
                
                for index, item in enumerate(todos):
                    item= item.strip("\n")
                    row = f"{index+1}-{item.capitalize()}"
                    print(row)  
            
            case 'edit':
                number= input("Enter a number: ")
                print(number)
                new_todo= input("Enter new tod0:")
                todos[int(number)-1]= new_todo
                print(new_todo)
            case "complete":
                number = int(input("Number of the todo:"))
                row=todos.pop(int(number))
                print(row)
            case "exit":
                break
        # # case whatever:
        # #     print("wrong message!!! Baaaka")
            

print('Bye!')
```

In above code, when entering new to dos and using complete, it shows following error:

```
 File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\python apps\app1.py", line 40, in <module>
    row=todos.pop(int(number))
NameError: name 'todos' is not defined
```

n above code, when entering new to dos and using complete, it shows following error:

```
 File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\python apps\app1.py", line 40, in <module>
    row=todos.pop(int(number))
NameError: name 'todos' is not defined
```

Comment: `todos` *isn't* defined until you select `add`, `show` or `display`.

Comment: You should probably define `todos` *before* the loop, operate on the list (and not the file) during the loop, and write the list back to the file after the loop.